# Deploying Container Group from Azure PowerShell

Tags: azure, deployment, containers, azure-cli, azure-container-registry

I am following the guide from Microsoft for deploying a container with sidecar for HTTPS access [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-container-group-ssl). However, I am trying to use one of my images, which I already pushed to ACR. I followed all the steps until

```
az container create --resource-group <myResourceGroup> --file deploy-aci.yaml
```

The contents of my deploy-aci.yaml file are these:

```
api-version: 2019-05-01
location: switzerlandnorth
name: app-with-ssl
properties:
  containers:
  - name: nginx-with-ssl
    properties:
      image: mcr.microsoft.com/oss/nginx/nginx:1.15.5-alpine
      ports:
      - port: 443
        protocol: TCP
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 1.0
          memoryInGB: 1.5
      volumeMounts:
      - name: nginx-config
        mountPath: /etc/nginx
  - name: my-container
    properties:
      image: my-registry/my-image:latest
      ports:
      - port: 80
        protocol: TCP
      resources:
        requests:
          cpu: 1.0
          memoryInGB: 1.5
  volumes:
  - secret:
      ssl.crt: base64-encoded-cert
      ssl.key: base64-encoded-key
      nginx.conf: base64-encoded-conf-content
    name: nginx-config
  ipAddress:
    ports:
    - port: 443
      protocol: TCP
    type: Public
  osType: Linux
tags: null
type: Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups
```

When trying to run the container create command above, I am getting this error:

> (InaccessibleImage) The image
> 'my-registry/my-image:latest'
> in container group 'app-with-ssl' is not accessible. Please check the
> image and registry credential. Code: InaccessibleImage Message: The
> image
> 'my-registry/my-image:latest'
> in container group 'app-with-ssl' is not accessible. Please check the
> image and registry credential.

I tried running the above command and also giving it the credentials to my registry, like this:

```
az container create --resource-group my-resource-group --file deploy-aci.yaml --registry-login-server my-server.azurecr.io --registry-username my-registry --registry-password my-password
```

I also tried pulling the image on my local computer, which I could with no problem. The image is publicly available (Basic pricing plan, I can't set it to private) and I checked my credentials to be correct. Any idea on where else I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I believe it needs the full URL for the image. So, in `deploy-aci.yaml` replace this line

```yaml
image: my-registry/my-image:latest
```

with something like

```yaml
image: mcr.microsoft.com/my-registry/my-image:latest
```

Comment: I tried doing this, the error is the same: The image 'mcr.microsoft.com/my-registry/my-image:latest' in container group 'app-with-ssl' is not accessible

Comment: @GabrielStancu So, I understand the repo is public, but I _think_ the ACI resource still needs IAM permissions to the ACR.